# Avast antivirus found Malwaregen[trj] on Mac

Tags: malware

I was running an Avast scan and I found Malwaregen[trj] in the utorrent section. I never used utorrent. Never. And suddenly this comes up. Does this mean someone was spying on me through a rootkit?

Malwarebytes never showed anything. However, the interesting thing is when I ran malwarebytes, it said "scanning adware", etc. And in-between, there comes "scanning trojan". And it comes up with nothing.

Avast says that it couldn't scan 18 files or something. Is my Macbook hacked? Is someone spying on me?

And by the way, I did install utorrent.

Comment: Just because you never used it doesn't mean anything - you installed it and uTorrent seems to have a [history of shipping with malware](https://www.reddit.com/r/torrents/comments/2w8wff/utorrent_now_with_virus/).

Comment: also from the original source?

Comment: yes - i would imagine it's adware of some sort.

Comment: but adware doesnt have rootkit capability

Comment: You say that you *installed* it, but insist that you never *ran* it, and you are shocked that there is malware. I'm confused why you make this distinction, and why you are then shocked. If the program had an infection, then it is reasonable that the infection would be found.

Comment: Why do you believe there is a rootkit involved somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be more probable that you downloaded a torrent that had some malware in it. I doubt the guys over at uTorrent would risk putting malware in their binaries :) (unless you downloaded uTorrent from an unofficial source).

A trojan can be used for spying, but more often than not, unless it is a targeted attack, it usually means other things such as stealing your credentials, stealing files, adding your computer to a botnet to mine bitcoins or click ads etc.

Antiviruses could be wrong. But better safe than sorry. Unless you can eliminate the threat, you might want to consider reinstalling your Mac OS.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43831/discussion-on-answer-by-0x23212f-avast-antivirus-found-malwaregentrj-on-mac).